# how to get start specific level in VR mode after build package?

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

Am having project with 2 levels, one level is simple fps and another two levels are VR levels. when am building package the VR levels are not starting properly, if i did start in VR checked with project settings then it will work fine. So, i want to make level start in VR with the command for tht VR levels to start in VR mode.

Comment: If you're looking for a way to launch VR mode via BP, take a look at the EnableHMD node.

Answer (score 0):

Try the console command *vr.bEnableHMD* set to 1 after loading the map.